# After I distribute my Django/Django-Rest-Framework project, I can not request its `media` and `static` directory

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a Django/Django-Rest-Framework project, and it only provides the APIs.

This is one of the drf APIs, I request the remote ipaddress in the browser:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I can not request its static resources.

I am not sure whether when Django APIs distribute, I will config the nginx for static and media placement.

If need Nginx config for Django APIs static resources, How can I config it?

this is an example of nginx vhost configure file:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name www.abc.xyz;

    access_log logs/www.abc.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/website/;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

     location ~ /media/*\.(jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|swf)$
        {
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
            root /var/www/html/python_backend/abc;
            break;
        }


    location /api/ {
            proxy_pass      http://101.20.32.76:8000/api/;
            proxy_redirect  off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

    location /media/ {
            proxy_pass      http://101.20.32.76:8000/media/;
            proxy_redirect  off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

}
```

You see the `localtion /`:

```
    location / {
        root /var/www/html/website/;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
```

because my Django/Django-Rest-Framework is only provide APIs, there is no such `index.html` files, so I don't know how to config it.

and the `http://101.20.32.76:8000/media/` I can not access, so the configuration of `location /media/` and `location /static/` is invalid right?

---

**EDIT-1**

I deploy in my remote server (CentOS7.2)
and in my remote repo, there are `static` directory and `media` directory, because I pushed them from local repo, they are not in `.gitignore`.

---

**EDIT-2**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

this is the configuration of my `settings.py`.

Comment: What is your `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` set to?
What directory is your code deployed in? 
Why are you serving static files from what appears to be your application server? Why not have Nginx serve static files directly?

Comment: @rtindru See my edit-2, friend.

Comment: Do you want the static content to be served by nginx or django?

Comment: @syntonym all OK. but if use nginx, I don't know how to config.

Comment: @syntonym By the way, can the django production project can served by dajngo too?

Answer (score 0):

During your application deployment; you'll need to run `python manage.py collectstatic`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic

> Collects the static files into STATIC_ROOT.
>   Files are searched by using the enabled finders. The default is to
>   look in all locations defined in STATICFILES_DIRS and in the 'static'
>   directory of apps specified by the INSTALLED_APPS

Read this for more info on how and when to collect static and how to serve static assets with Django: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-the-site-and-your-static-files-from-the-same-server

Comment: I have the static directory, because I pushed it from local repo.

Comment: You need to run `collectstatic` on the remote machine; check the link to the Django documentation in the updated answer above.

Comment: I removed the static fold, and collectstatic success, still not work.